# Kendo UI Mobile Drawer with MVC View structure

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-mobile

Is there any way to use the Kendo UI (mobile) drawer as navigation in the main _Layout for your views and have the MobileListView items link to different MVC views instead of MobileViews all listed on one page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been working with this quite a while now (both the asp.net mvc helpers and the javascript library), and I've arrived at the conclusion that it's too much hassle for this to work with mvc. Also, the newly released asp.net mvc helpers don't work satisfactory yet, as they have a few bugs and kinks in regards to ui and navigating between links.

Let me know if you find a solution to this!

Comment: Sorry!  It was completely an accident... if it was me that did it.